# What is a better way to break java list in Map of Maps?

Tags: java, java-stream

We have

```
List<persons> persons;
```

and we need

```
 Map<age,Map<income,Person>> results
```

the way I am doing it now is :

```
      ages.stream().forEach(a -> {
        Map<Integer,Person> tmpMap  = new HashMap<>();
        incomes.stream().forEach(i -> {
            Person p = persons.stream().filter(
            u -> u.getAge() == a.getAge() && 
             u.getIncome() == i.getIncome())
             .findAny().orElse(null);
             tmpMap.put(i.getIncome(), p);
        });
       returns.put(a.getAge(),tmpMap);
    });
```

it seems like there should be a better way of doing this.

Comment: Have you considered Guava library? I believe it has implementation for what you need.

Comment: Not sure how your map and classes look like, but do you know that, you might have a problem if couple persons share age or income

Comment: Side note: Java class names start with uppercase letters by convention. Ignoring that convention makes it harder for other java programmers to read your code; so consider fixing that.

Comment: off-topic - consider using `collection.forEach()` instead of `collection.stream().forEach()` - the latter is a bit of a waste

Comment: @user902383 Yes, I fixed that, I was looking for more efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like it works.

```
List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(
        new Person("One", 21, 100),
        new Person("Two", 21, 75),
        new Person("Three", 42, 100),
        new Person("Four", 42, 120),
        new Person("Five", 9, 100)
);
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Person>> map = people.stream()
        // Gather all ages into a Map<Age,List<Person>>
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getAge))
        // Walk that transient Map.
        .entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                // Key is the age.
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                // Value is a Map<income,person>
                e -> e.getValue()
                // Roll each of the same age into a Map<Income,Person>
                .stream().collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(
                                // Key is income.
                                Person::getIncome,
                                // Value is the Person.
                                Function.identity()
                        ))));
```

I roll your list into a `Map<Age,List<Person>>` using a `groupingBy` and then stream it's entrySet and collect that into the final form.

**This will fail if two people of the same age have the same income** because that will violate the inner Map. Use [Alexander's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37327645/823393) if you are happy with the natural enhancement of generating a `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<Person>>>`.

**Added**

@Holger has pointed out in a comment that this can be done in a much simpler and more elegant way. Please use this form instead/

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Person>> map2 = people.stream()
        .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Person::getAge,
                        Collectors.toMap(Person::getIncome, Function.identity())));
```

FYI - Here's the Person class I used. Note the `equals` and `hashcode` are implemented.

```
class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;
    private final int income;


    public Person(String name, int age, int income) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.income = income;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public int getIncome() {
        return income;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" + "name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", income=" + income + '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 59 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name);
        hash = 59 * hash + this.age;
        hash = 59 * hash + this.income;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Person other = (Person) obj;
        if (this.age != other.age) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.income != other.income) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.name, other.name)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: one left e -> e.getValue()

Comment: @NicolasFilotto - Tried it. Didn't work, probably because I then stream the entries.

Comment: Why don’t you use the [`groupingBy` collector that allows you to specify another `Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) instead of this baroque combination of three streaming operations?

Comment: @Holger - Because OP wanted `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Person>>`, not `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<Person>>>`. Is there a neater way of achieving that?

Comment: `collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getAge, Collectors.toMap(Person::getIncome, Function.identity())));` — nobody says that the downstream collector has to be another `groupingBy` collector.

Comment: @Holger - It's strange how lambdas make you think in a different way. This is why I need to keep practicing.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick

```
List<person> persons = Arrays.asList(
    new person(22, 1000), 
    new person(25, 1500), 
    new person(22, 2500), 
    new person(32, 5000)
);
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<person>>> map = persons.stream().collect(
    groupingBy(person::getAge, groupingBy(person::getIncome))
);
System.out.println(map);
```

**Output:**

```
{32={5000=[person{age=32, income=5000}]}, 22={2500=[person{age=22, income=2500}], 1000=[person{age=22, income=1000}]}, 25={1500=[person{age=25, income=1500}]}}
```

**NB:** The result is not exactly what you expect as you will get a `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<person>>>` instead of `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, person>>` but I assume that your initial question is not correct because if you have two persons with the same age and income, you will have only one person in your map instead of two

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I don't understand how somebody with your reputation still don't know that you are supposed to leave a comment when you down vote

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon ok I see thx for sharing, but why do you say that it is wrong? Don't you believe that the question is simply wrong as I mentioned in my NB?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto  Indeed the original code was wrong, I fixed it, but I hope you got the idea. We are looking for more efficient way to do it.

Comment: What I propose here is the most efficient way

Comment: The proposal of @OldCurmudgeon is the best answer if you don't want to cover the case where 2 people have the same age and income, if you want to cover it I don't believe that it is your best choice because it does it with 2 streams instead of one and the code is hard to read and maintain, but it is your choice now

Comment: Replacing the downstream collector with a `toMap` collector is no magic, that’s still much better (and more efficient) than the solution of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at *Collectors.groupingBy()*:

```
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<Person>>> map = persons.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(person -> person.getAge(),Collectors.groupingBy(person -> person.getIncome())));
```

This should do your thing.

Comment: This creates a `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<Person>>>`. OP wanted a `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Person>>`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not (I assume your type is person, not persons, you used both)

```
  for (person p : persons)
   {
       if (!results.containsKey(p.getAge())
             results.put(p.getAge(), new HashMap<income,persons>());
       results.get(p.getAge()).put(p.getIncome(), p);
   }
```

Comment: people are so inclined to use streams they forget that the same thing can be achieved in a different, much neater way. kudos to you sir.

Comment: Even that works better with Java 8: `for (Person p : persons) results.computeIfAbsent(p.getAge(), key -> new HashMap<>()).put(p.getIncome(), p);`

Answer (score 0):

I second YaRiK; a [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) [`Table<Integer, Integer, Set<Person>>`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) would work nicely here. You should use a `Set<Person>` to avoid collisions, like user902383 suggests. The streams API isn't always the right tool, and this looks to me like a case where a traditional iterative loop will be [much easier to read](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/FunctionalExplained#caveats).

Try this:

```
Table<Integer, Integer, Set<Person>> table = HashBasedTable.create();
for (Person p : persons) {
  Set<Person> s = table.get(p.getAge(), p.getIncome());
  if (s == null) {
    s = new HashSet<>();
    table.put(p.getAge(), p.getIncome(), s);
  }
  s.add(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement your own collector for achieving this. With the help of Guava you can do it in one line:

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Person>> result = persons.stream().collect(HashMap::new, (store, person) -> store.put(person.getAge(), ImmutableMap.of(person.getIncome(), person)), HashMap::putAll);
```